# Osculating space of a curve on Segre

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry

Given an analytic curve $\gamma(t)$ on the Segre variety $X = Seg(\mathbb{P} V_1 \times \cdots \times \mathbb{P} V_d)$, such that 
$$
[\gamma(0) \wedge \gamma'(0) \wedge \cdots \wedge \gamma^{(k-1)}(0)] \ne 0,
$$
 but $[\gamma^{(k)}(0)], \dots, [\gamma^{(m-1)}(0)]$ are linear combinations of $[\gamma(0)], \dots, [\gamma^{(k-1)}(0)]$, and
$$[\gamma(0) \wedge \gamma'(0) \wedge \cdots \wedge \gamma^{(k-1)}(0) \wedge \gamma^{(m)}(0)] \ne 0.$$

I think we can always find another curve $\alpha(t) \subset X$, such that 
$$
[\gamma(0) \wedge \cdots \wedge \gamma^{(i)}(0)] = [\alpha(0) \wedge \cdots \wedge \alpha^{(i)}(0)]
$$ for each $1 \le i \le k-1$, and 
$$[\gamma(0) \wedge \gamma'(0) \wedge \cdots \wedge \gamma^{(k-1)}(0) \wedge \gamma^{(m)}(0)] = [\alpha(0) \wedge \alpha'(0) \wedge \cdots \wedge \alpha^{(k-1)}(0) \wedge \alpha^{(k)}(0)].$$ 
I'm sorry for my ignorance of differential geometry. Is this correct? If so, how can I prove this? I think this should be a very general phenomenon, is it true for any manifold? Thanks a lot!